# Why do we use "об этом" for 'about it"

Tags: падежи

In the prepositional case, a phrase "about it", is usually translated as "об этом". Is "этом" in this phrase, a declension from demonstrative pronoun "этот" ? And if that's so, why there is no noun after a demonstrative pronoun?

Comment: Demonstrative pronoun in English is "this". Do you always add a noun after "about this"?

Answer (score 9):

> "about it", is usually translated as "об этом"

Could also be *про это*. There's even a poem [Про это](http://www.ilibrary.ru/text/2392/p.1/index.html) by Mayakovskij.

> why there is no noun after a demonstrative pronoun?

Because *Это* may also be used **in place of a noun**. Sort of *This* or *That*. For example,

> *Это* кажется мне странным. --> *It* seems strange to me.
>   Что Вы *под этим* подразумеваете? --> What do you mean by *that*?
>   Что *это* такое? --> What is *this*?
>   etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Is "этом" in this phrase [about it, об этом], a declension from demonstrative pronoun
>   "этот" ?

*Это* is the demonstrative pronoun of neuter gender. *Этот* is the same pronoun, but of masculine gender, and *эта* is that of feminine gender. Sometimes the way the three are inflected for case is homonymous.

Here`s an example.

- `So what are we going to do about IT?` — `Ну и что мы с этим будем делать?` (Instrumental case of *это*, neuter gender.)
- `So what are we going to do about HIM?` — `Hу и что мы с этим будем делать?` (Instrumental case of *этот*, masculine gender.)

Same form, different meaning.

> And if that's so, why there is no noun after a demonstrative pronoun?

Because in this case this demonstrative pronoun would be self-sufficient as the indirect object of the sentence.